# Python Dictionary comprehension pre-executing methods

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm fairly new to the python programming language, I'm looking to garner a little more understanding as to how the dict comprehension works (if this is actually what it is in the first place!)

```
return {
    'hello': method_call_1()
    'goodbye': method_call_2()
    'hello2': method_call_3()
}['hello']
```

Looking at this, I would assume that `method_call_1()` would be executed because that's the dictionary key the return is looking for. However it seems in my program that the other two methods are executed (or I get an error for the lack of their existence) regardless of whether they are returned or not.

Is this standard behaviour? My only assumption is that the python compiler will pre-execute the methods calls before they're actually used, rather than only executing the method chosen.

Off the top of my head, I could probably get around this with something like:

```
x = return {
    'hello': 'method_call_1'
    'goodbye': 'method_call_2'
    'hello2': 'method_call_3'
}['hello']

x()
```

But this seems like it would be inappropriate practice, is there any better way to go about this?

Comment: First you build the dictionary. To build it, the functions that provide the values have to be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating the dict, Python wants to store result values of every expression, so every function you call inside the dict will be evaluated in the generation process, not at the call process.

If you are only going to store functions in there to call them later, you can store the memory address of the function. That is, the name of the function without parenthesis.

That way you can call them later asi you tried to do in the second code block:

```
x = return {
    'hello': method_call_1,
    'goodbye': method_call_2,
    'hello2': method_call_3,
}['hello']

x()
```

Comment: This works, ended up using getattr because the method was in a module but this was the general implementation. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The python compiler is actually trying to execute the methods since you are calling them ( `()` ), so the return value of this function is assign to the value of the dict.

you can do something like this:

```
def func_1():
    return 1
def func_2():
    return func_1
def func_3():
    return func_1()

def select_funct(i):

    selection = {1: func_1,
                 2: func_2,
                 3: func_3(),
                }
    return selection[i]

print(select_funct(1)())

print(select_funct(2)()())

print(select_funct(3))
```